# How to get Custom Facts only in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am using `Ansible` for configuring the remote nodes. Now, i need to get some information from these nodes to take decisions at `ansible master`.

So, i tried the Custom Facts.

```js
1. Created facts.d directory in /etc/ansible/
2. Created a file test.facts in facts.d directory.
3. Response of the test.facts is JSON.
4. Execution permission is given for the facts file.
```

It's working. But, i felt its slow because it gathers default facts as well.

Is there a way to receive the custom facts of `test.facts` file alone?

Comment: See [gather_subset](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset).

Comment: Hi @VladimirBotka. Thanks for the reply. I did see this gather_subset. But what should be the value for this attribute? `gather_subset=test`? all and min are values which are accepted. I am not sure, how to include this test file alone.

Comment: That is what i am doing @VladimirBotka. Thanks for the response though. Will update the question if i find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot limit to a specific `.fact` file alone, but you can easilly:

- filter out anything but the `ansible_local` facts
- limit to the subset containing the above facts.

Although I'm not quite sure this will have a very noticeable impact on performance, after some blind tries on my local machine, the following seems to work:

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a 'gather_subset=!all,!min,virtual' -a filter=ansible_local
```

Meanwhile, if facts gathering time really becomes an issue, you should consider switching to a [persistent facts cache plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/459ea5a4a48b770f09be9b8f48f2593594f348f2/examples/ansible.cfg#L249) and review your [gathering strategy](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/459ea5a4a48b770f09be9b8f48f2593594f348f2/examples/ansible.cfg#L24)

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. Maybe you are right, i will not be able to limit the default facts. All i can do is minimise it using the subset been set to min. Apart from that, will look into these `persistent facts cache plugin`. Thank you once again.